# Dovecot SMTPD Sasl auth error: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sasl

I've googled this error and nothing I've read/tried works - anyone know what it is

Error log:

```
Feb 23 22:35:36 localhost postfix/smtpd[5278]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 23 22:35:36 localhost postfix/smtpd[5278]: warning: SASL: Connect to smtpd failed: No such file or directory
Feb 23 22:35:36 localhost postfix/smtpd[5278]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Feb 23 22:35:37 localhost postfix/master[5214]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 5278 exit status 1
Feb 23 22:35:37 localhost postfix/master[5214]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

postfix/main.cf:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smptd_sasl_path = private/auth
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
```

dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf:

```
  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
```

Dovecot is available in postfix:

```
[root@localhost ~]# postconf -a
cyrus
dovecot
```

Socket:

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# ls -l /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
srw-rw-rw-. 1 postfix postfix 0 Feb 23 22:46 /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
```

Telnet time out straight away:

```
[root@localhost ~]# telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Auth works:

```
[root@localhost ~]# doveadm auth adrian
Password:
passdb: adrian auth succeeded
extra fields:
  user=adrian
```

OS: Centos 6.4
Dovecot: 2.1.17
Postfix: 2.6.6

**Edit result of postconf -n:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = 192.168.124.0/24 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_domains
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks        permit_sasl_authenticated        reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: What's the output of `postconf -n`?

Comment: Cannot post - added as edit

Comment: Do you have a file `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf` with the following content: `pwcheck_method: saslauthd\n mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN`? (mind the newline)

Comment: And I have `smtp_sasl_type = dovecot` in my postfix config more.

Comment: Actually your case is weird... The error log was specific for cyrus SASL, because [postfix looking for `smtpd.conf` file](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_cyrus). And yet, your configuration states that you use dovecot for auth service :(. Did you override it in `master.cf`?

Comment: Looks like cyrus SASL got dragged in with the postfix package install. But why is it trying to use it when it clearly says supports dovecot but is ignoring.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see, there's no `smtpd_sasl_path` in our output of `postconf -n`

Why? The answer is easy. Because there's no `smtpd_sasl_path` set. Have a look at your first snippet: There's a typo in it. You wrote **smptd_sasl_path = private/auth** -- but there's a difference between  sm*tp*d and sm*pt*d.

Because Postfix doesn't have informations where to find the socket, Postfix is claiming the "failing connect".

Fix it and it'll work. :-)

And, at the end: Remember for the next time: Reading `postconf -n` carefully and make sure, that Postfix has the same information as you believe Postfix should have, is always an important step to find the failure.

Comment: +1 for finding a typo  :)

Comment: Thank you Peer and sorry to bother you as the author about such a silly mistake - I stared out that code for hours even looking for a type - just did not see it.

Comment: Wow, I found the guy who keeps resetting my irc connection.

Comment: +1 because I spent hours and my issue was smtp_ instead of smtpd_ ...gotta have the d.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error, different issue.

Had to edit `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf` and uncomment `unix_listener` and add the `user` and `group` lines.

```
service auth {
   unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
      mode = 0660
      user = postfix
      group = postfix
   }
```